# VBA Replace only first occurrance of found Value in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I want my code to replace only the first occurrance of a value in a excel cell when I press the replace button. the problem of what the following code does is, it replaces all occurrances at the same time not one by one. but I need it to do one after the other every time I press the button. 
What would be the solution to this?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    StrngValue = UserForm1.TextBox2.Text

    If Trim(StrngValue) = "" Then Exit Sub
    For Each wos In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With wos.UsedRange
            Set rng = .Cells.Find(what:=StrngValue)
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                Do Until rng Is Nothing
                    Application.Goto Loc, False
                    StrngRepl = Userform2.TextBox1.Text
                    If Not StrngRepl = "" Then
                    rng.Value = StrngRepl
                    Set rng = .FindNext(rng)
                    Else
                    Exit Sub
                    End If
                Loop
            End If
        End With
        Set rng = Nothing

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this, but why don't you use the Excel standard functionality

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    StrngValue = UserForm1.TextBox2.Text

    If Trim(StrngValue) = "" Then Exit Sub
    For Each wos In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With wos.UsedRange
            Set Rng = .Cells.Find(what:=StrngValue)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                'Do Until Rng Is Nothing
                'Application.Goto Loc, False
                StrngRepl = Userform2.TextBox1.Text
                If Not StrngRepl = "" Then
                    Rng.Value = StrngRepl
                    Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
                Else
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                'Loop
            End If
        End With
        Set Rng = Nothing

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: lol when I commented off the loop it crashed... maybe I needed a break of coding... Thank you anyway it works like a charm.
do you mean inputbox? I need the possibility to skip a value and thats only possible with an userform.

Comment: there is still one problem, I have multiple sheets and it replaces the first occurrances in every sheet on the first click. how can I change it to work on the first sheet then on the next one?

Comment: Based on your comments the excel standard funcitonality should be  absolutely enough for you. If you want to skip a value you just click on `Find Next` instead of `Replace`. And you can also switch between worksheet and workbook.